# How to keep an MKAnnotation View Image fixed on the center of the map as the user pans and moves the map around (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

using target 8.0 MapKit, I would like to define an MKAnnotation (such as a pin, or a custom one) that remains fixed on the center of the map view as the user moves the map around. Once the user stops moving the map, I would like to be able to read the new coordinates of the annotation. How can I do this? This in swift, thank you soo much

Comment: In Ray Wenderlich's tutorial (https://www.raywenderlich.com/109888/google-maps-ios-sdk-tutorial) they're using an UIImageView pinned to the center of the view. There are methods for when the maps stop panning, which you can use to display the coordinates.

Comment: @HideCode did u used google map or apple map ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this link to accomplish this task.They are doing something very similar to your requirement. Its quite descriptive. [Link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/109888/google-maps-ios-sdk-tutorial)

Comment: Yes it´s help me. Thank you soo much